# How to store SockJS object into localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, sockjs

I'm using the following example from [Spring-Websocket](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket) to create and use SockJS object:

```
....
var socket = new SockJS('/gs-guide-websocket');
....
```

I have integrated this to our application, but whenever I refresh the page. new `SockJS` object is getting created, hence new connection is getting created.

I thought that the best solution is to store the `socket` object into `localStorage`, but unsuccessful, since `localStorage` accepts String only.

I tried to call

```
localStorage.setItem("websocket", JSON.stringify(socket));
```

But whenever I get the object back and call `JSON.parse()` I noticed some the data inside the object has been gone.

How can I store it in `localStorage`? 
Or maybe there is a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible. When you create a connection,it will be closed when you close this page. So it is pointless.